# How to configure importScript when using vue-cli-pwa plugin

Tags: workbox

The auto generated `service-worker.js` import workbox like below:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");
```

As my client may not have the access to `googleapis.com`, I want to serve the workbox from my server, like the [document](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw#using_local_workbox_files_instead_of_cdn) describe.

```
importScripts('/third_party/workbox/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.setConfig({
  modulePathPrefix: '/third_party/workbox/'
});
```

But I can't find a way to configure this from `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa`.

**Extra**: the `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` is using `workbox@4.3.1`, I can not find the matched document. The document serving on google is for version 5.1.2.

**File assets**

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',  // 自定义功能
        workboxOptions: {
          swSrc: './src/sw.js',
          swDest: 'service-worker.js',
        },
    }
}
```

sw.js

```
importScripts('/third-party/workbox/workbox-sw.js');
workbox.setConfig({
  modulePathPrefix: '/third-party/workbox/'
});
console.log('hello from service worker');
```

**output:**

```
importScripts("/precache-manifest.247d2cef5fd7daa4fb6945d4ca3b21f4.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

importScripts('/third-party/workbox/workbox-sw.js');
workbox.setConfig({
  modulePathPrefix: '/third-party/workbox/'
});
console.log('hello from service worker');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find v4 documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/v4), or just [read the source code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v4.3.1/packages/workbox-webpack-plugin/src/lib/get-workbox-sw-imports.js).

In short, if you still want to use `GenerateSW` mode:

```js
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    workboxOptions: {
      importWorkboxFrom: 'local'
    }
  }
}
```